# Can any one explain how to mount a netconf device in opendaylight from a maven project java application

Tags: java, maven, opendaylight, netconf

Can any one explain how to mount a netconf device in opendaylight from a maven project java application
Any one please help in creating a starter project template for mounting netconf device in opendaylight from maven project
The doc is not clear on this topic
I need some clarity regarding what all karaf feature are need to be installed and archetype for creating project
My intention is to create a southbound plugin to communicate to netconf device